# PowerDesigner - how to change column name/code and store the old one via user-defined Form - kind of OnChange event

Tags: event-handling, eventhandler, powerdesigner

I need to change a column name/code of a selected column (in GUI) in an invoked user defined Form, event before Apply/OK.

Mainly, I need to keep old name/code in an extended attribute to create migration script later. Which event handler to use?  (Validate event has already changed name/code, not the old one).

Comment: You could use model events: `OnModelOpen` to store the name/code initial state, and `OnModelSave` to record the modifications. Or you could display calculated attributes in the form, with the appropriate Get/Set methods.

Comment: Good idea, Pascal. It means "remember column initial names" when model is opened, and evaluate/process accumulated differences on saving the model or whenever later. Viable, even though a little bit clumsy, as all columns collection has to be cycled through on opening. With a big data model (3000 tables)  it may take a few seconds. If I find nothing better, I'll go this way.